# Get data from different table using a foreign key in a rails view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a new .html.erb file where I'm attempting to list all of the teams and their opponents. I have 2 tables: a users (team) table and a records table. The records table has 2 columns (user_id, opponent_user_id) referencing the same users table.

My view file:

```
   <% @record.each do |record| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= record.user.name %></td>          
       <td><%= record.opponent_user_id %></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Rather than using record.user_id, I was able to replace the id with the name of the user by using record.user.name. I am unable to do the same with the opponent team however. I tried using

```
    <td><%= record.opponent_user_id.user.name %></td>
```

but that didn't work. How can I replace the opponent_user_id with the actual name?

Additional info below

Controller

```
  def prof
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @record = Record.where(user_id: @user.id)
  end
```

Table schema

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

  create_table "records", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "opponent_user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_records_on_user_id"
  end
```

Thanks for the help. I'm still new to rails. Any additional feedback for what I shouldn't be doing this way would likewise be appreciated.

Comment: check the given answer below and let me for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :opponent_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "opponent_user_id"
end
```

In User model:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records, class_name: "Record", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :opponent_user_records, class_name: "Record", foreign_key: "opponent_user_id"
end
```

Here by:-

```
  def prof
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @records = @user.records
  end
```

And

```
   <% @records.each do |record| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= record.user.name %></td>          
       <td><%= record.opponent_user.name %></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: @JackSmith make sure once you have mentioned `belongs_to :opponent_user` in rails 5 its mandatory to provide  `opponent_user_id` while you creating and event, so if you don't have any such requirement than you can provide it `optional: true`.  thanks

Comment: This will create 2n+1 queries, I believe. You probably want to use `includes` to eager load the `user` and `opponent_user` records. You can learn about `includes` in [Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) from the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) docs.

Comment: @jvillian  `@records = Record.includes(:user).where(users: { id: params[:id] })` make me correct if i'm wrong.